# Tagging a .txt file from Inaugural Address Corpus

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tagging, part-of-speech

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out.  New to coding.  I'm trying to read a .txt file, tokenize it, pos tag the words in it.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
import re

file = open('1865-Lincoln.txt', 'r').readlines()
text = word_tokenize(file)
string = str(text)
nltk.pos_tag(string)
```

My problem is, it keeps giving me the `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` error.

Answer (score 1):

word_tokenize is expecting a string but file.readlines() gives you a list.
Just convert the list to a string will solve the issue.

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
import re

file = open('test.txt', 'r').readlines()
text =''
for line in file:
    text+=line
text = word_tokenize(text)
string = str(text) # remove it if want to tag by words and pass text directly to post_tag:)
nltk.pos_tag(string)
```

Comment: interestingly, that tags every letter in the file, rather than the words.  crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the following:

```
import nltk
# nltk.download('all') # only for the first time when you use nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
import re

with open('1865-Lincoln.txt') as f: # with - open is recommended for file reading
    lines = f.readlines() # first get all the lines from file, store it
    for i in range(0, len(lines)): # for each line, do the following
        token_text = word_tokenize(lines[i]) # tokenize each line, store in token_text
        print (token_text) # for debug purposes
        pos_tagged_token = nltk.pos_tag(token_text) # pass the token_text to pos_tag()
        print (pos_tagged_token)
```

For a text file containing:

> user is here
>
> pass is there

The output was:

> ['user', 'is', 'here']
>
> [('user', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('here', 'RB')]
>
> ['pass', 'is', 'there']
>
> [('pass', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('there', 'RB')]

It worked for me, I'm on Python 3.6, if that should matter. Hope this helps!

**EDIT 1:**
So your issue was you were passing a *list of strings* to `pos_tag()`, whereas doc says

> A part-of-speech tagger, or POS-tagger, processes a sequence of words, and attaches a part of speech tag to each word

Hence you needed to pass it line by line i. e. *string by string*. That is why you were getting a `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` error.

Comment: @Archivist Did this solve your question? If yes, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer

Answer (score -1):

Most probably the `1865-Lincoln.txt` refers to the inaugural speech of president Lincoln. It's available in NLTK from https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/blob/gh-pages/packages/corpora/inaugural.zip

The original source of the document comes from the [Inaugural Address Corpus](http://search.language-archives.org/record.html?id=languagecommons_org_Inaugural-Address-Corpus-1789-2009)

If we check how [NLTK is reading the file using LazyCorpusReader](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/__init__.py#L125), we see that the files are Latin-1 encoded.

```
inaugural = LazyCorpusLoader(
    'inaugural', PlaintextCorpusReader, r'(?!\.).*\.txt', encoding='latin1')
```

If you have the default encoding set to `utf8`, most probably that's where the `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` is occurring

You should open the file with an explicit encoding and decode the string properly, i.e.

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag

tagged_lines = []
with open('test.txt', encoding='latin1') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        tagged_lines.append(pos_tag(word_tokenize(line)))
```

But technically, you can access the `inagural` corpus directly as a corpus object in NLTK, i.e.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import inaugural
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>> tagged_sents = [pos_tag(sent) for sent in inaugural.sents('1865-Lincoln.txt')]
```

Comment: Open a file with the right encoding, avoid messing with encoding of strings after a file is opened.